# How should I handle answers to questions which I don't plan on trying

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I ask a question and some time passes without an answer. I end up following a work around/patchy fix.

Then, a user comes and answers my question. However, I don't plan on going back and updating my original code (I plan on keeping the patch). Should I accept any answer? Should I delete the question?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ignoring the answer and letting it sit forever. Even if *you* don't need it, other people may still find it useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why delete the question, particularly if it has already garnered answers that may help other users with that same problem?

If you think that the answer is useful, upvote it.  If you think that it's not useful, downvote it.  If you think that it's the best answer to your question, feel free to accept it.

If you just can't be bothered to evaluate the answer and see if it's even a good one, feel free to not provide any feedback at all.  Other community members will be able to vote on the answer, allowing other readers to have an idea as to its quality.

How much and what kind of feedback you choose to give is *entirely* up to you.

Comment: Should I accept questions that I haven't personally verified? Its not uncommon to receive incorrect answers

Comment: @AakilFernandes Of course you shouldn't accept an answer that you haven't actually evaluated.  If you don't want to take the time to evaluate the answer, then don't evaluate it.  Providing feedback without knowing if it's actually valid is actively harmful if you are incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

You also should think about providing your workaround as an answer.